# Is rel=canonical almost useless for an SPA?

Tags: seo, rel-canonical, single-page-application

In this article: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html, mistake 3 says you can only use the `rel=canonical` setting once per page.

As a result, if not, in a big SPA where the site header is always the same isn't `rel=canonical` relatively useless since you can only use it for 1 set of links? Is there some way I'm not thinking of that allows you to get around this?

Comment: Google understands dynamic meta tags.   If you are using push state to change the URL on your SPA and set the meta tags based on the URL on page load Google should understand that.